# Count the number of rows for each csv, faster code

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder with several csv files. When I open them in notepad I can see the number of lines/rows. This works. However, this is a manual check. I wanted to automate this with the following code:

```
import os
import csv

with open("number of lines check.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Desktop\folder'):
        for filename in files:
            with open(os.path.join(path, filename), "r", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter ="\t")
                data = list(reader)
                row_count = len(data)
                f = os.path.join(path, filename)
                a.write(str(f)+" "+str(row_count) + os.linesep)
```

This works, it gives me a file with the filename and row counts. However, my problem here is this code for some reasons takes a very long time to run. I am not sure why. I assume, it is because it has to read in each csv? When I open the files in notepad this works quite fast and the number of rows is displayed without any delay. So I was not sure if my code is not good or if there is a faster implementation?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using the data for anything other than counting the rows. There's no need for a CSV reader for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using the data for anything other than counting the rows. There's no need for a CSV reader for that.

Files are iterable by line so you can loop over it and count iterations. The writing out also has overhead so writing once will be faster.

```py
row_counts = {}

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Desktop\folder'):
    for filename in files:
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), "r", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
            rows = len(list(f))
            row_counts[filename] = rows

with open("number of lines check.txt", "w") as a:
    for f, count in row_counts.items():
        a.write(str(f)+" "+str(count) + os.linesep)
```

If the files are very large, it would be better to iterate over them and maintain a count so that you don't need to read the whole file at once.

```py
for filename in files:
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), "r", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
        rows = 0
        for _ in f: rows += 1
        row_counts[filename] = rows
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. Yes, I do have very large files. I tried to get your code running, but it does not work. Could you maybe post a full working example? Including the part for large files.

Comment: @BertHobe, sorry, writing code samples without running them never ends well. I've updated the sample, Do you want to try it again.

Comment: I am not sure if I implemented your code correctly. I updated my question with the two versions I tried. One does not work and the other still takes a very long time?

Comment: I missed the paths -> files change in the first edit but +1 for spotting that. Other than that, check the indentation, I meant for the second `with open(...` to be at the top level so that it runs after all the files are read.

Comment: How  long is a very long time? Longer than it did in the original version? Roughly how many files are you reading/how long are they?

Comment: Thanks for your ongoing support. I updated my edit in my question. It runs now and I corrected the indentation to top level. Please check again if I did it right. With my two files it takes almost 3 minutes. One file is 348kb with 5240 lines and the other 149mb with 716146 lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231368/discussion-between-holloway-and-berthobe).